# How do I include hover layout?

Tags: lightning-design-system, popover

I have a list of contacts, and I want to add a popover every time I hover on them, like this example (popover over account):

[image]

what i was able to do is this:

[image]

its comes together, but there are a few things i wasn't able to do:

1. remove the grey color there is behind the hover (not inside the pop-up)
2. move the pop up to the right, not below the label. or even better, make it dynamic and show the pop up where there is space on the screen, and if there isn't space make it smaller.
3. i want the pop-up to be on top of the data on the screen, and not have it moved.

this is the screen when the pop-up isnt there:

[image]

with the pop-up:

[image]

as you can see, the pop-up moves the rest of the data down.

this is the code so far.

CSS:

```
.THIS .parent-div-hover{ display: none; }
.THIS .child-div-content-hover:hover .parent-div-hover{ display : block; }
```

the component:

```
<div class="child-div-content-hover">
            <a id="tree0-node0-0-link"  tabindex="-1" onclick="{!c.showHidePanel}" role="presentation">
                <lightning:icon class="myIcon" iconName="standard:account" size="small"/>
                &nbsp;{!v.acc.Name}&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <label class="disabled"> ({!v.acc.Type}) {!v.acc.BillingCountry}</label>
            </a>
            <div class="parent-div-hover">
                <div class="slds-popover slds-popover--panel slds-nubbin--left-top" role="dialog">
                  <div class="slds-popover__header">
                    <div class="slds-media slds-media--center slds-m-bottom--small">
                      <div class="slds-media__figure">
                        <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-standard-account">
                          <lightning:icon class="myIcon" iconName="standard:account" size="small"/>
                          <span class="slds-assistive-text">Account</span> <!--whats this?-->
                        </span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="slds-media__body"><a href="#void" class="slds-text-heading--medium">{!v.acc.Name}</a></div> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-grid--pull-padded">
                      <div class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-2 slds-p-bottom--x-small">
                        <dl>
                          <dt>
                            <p class="slds-text-heading--label slds-truncate">Title</p>
                          </dt>
                          <dd>
                            <p class="slds-truncate">Body</p>
                          </dd>
                        </dl>
                      </div>
                      <div class="slds-col--padded slds-size--1-of-2 slds-p-bottom--x-small">
                        <dl>
                          <dt>
                            <p class="slds-text-heading--label slds-truncate">Title</p>
                          </dt>
                          <dd>
                            <p class="slds-truncate">Body</p>
                          </dd>
                        </dl>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

thanks for the help.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Questions must be related to a specific coding problem. Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: @MartinLezer you are correct. sorry about that. i modified my question with the code i have so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LightningDesignSystem.com site gives front-end developers some **guidance** and **pre-built HTML** that can be used as a base for building components using the framework (not necessarily on Lightning and/or on Salesforce, since you can use LDS outside the platform).

Unfortunately for you there is no Lightning Component for a popover, so you would need to write the HTML (as demonstrated on the LDS link in your post) to your pages/components. If you want this functionality on a standard page then you are out of luck since this doesn't seem to be customizable.

Comment: i wrote the pop-up with HTML, and encountered with some other problems, maybe you can assist? i updated my question